# awk inside another awk's system

Tags: awk, hashsum

I am given a file containing the md5 values for files within the same folder. The information is in the file `md5checksums.txt` in the following format:

```
b0da7ead9d82a3494d7e0a7099871ef4  ./GCF_000959505.1_ASM95950v1_assembly_report.txt
7ff32cbb16daf46c87b3546ad576ff66  ./GCF_000959505.1_ASM95950v1_assembly_stats.txt
034081da3aa0708f06c2ec1129e4aca9  ./GCF_000959505.1_ASM95950v1_cds_from_genomic.fna.gz
```

I want to do md5 checks for all the files. I got this command:

```
awk '{system("md5 "$2)}' md5checksums.txt
```

But this just gets the md5 values

```
MD5 (./GCF_000959505.1_ASM95950v1_assembly_report.txt) = b0da7ead9d82a3494d7e0a7099871ef4
MD5 (./GCF_000959505.1_ASM95950v1_assembly_stats.txt) = 7ff32cbb16daf46c87b3546ad576ff66
MD5 (./GCF_000959505.1_ASM95950v1_cds_from_genomic.fna.gz) = 3a30966523a36368ab432f666001f80a
```

I would like to extract the calculated md5 against the first column of `md5checksums.txt`
I thought I could do something like an awk inside an awk, but I can't get it to work:

```
awk '{system("md5 "$2" | awk HERE EVALUATE RESULTS AND CHECK IF EQUAL TO $1")}' md5checksums.txt
```

Comment: [BSD md5 vs GNU md5sum output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299833/bsd-md5-vs-gnu-md5sum-output-format). Give `md5` the `-r` option to produce the same output format as `md5sum`.

Comment: Great, but I still have to parse the results since they are given in 2 columns

Comment: do you want to check file againt their md5 sum ? Yes=> `md5sum -r` Or see if same file comme with new name ?

Comment: I suspect that this an escaping problem, you need to escape the `$` to stop it being interpreted by the outer awk. I am sure there are better answers though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a bit confused as to why you involve `awk` in this.

To verify the MD5 checksums in a file produced by GNU `md5sum`, you do

```
md5sum -c file.txt
```

Or, on an OpenBSD or NetBSD system whose `md5` utility supports `-c filename` (not FreeBSD or macOS):

```
md5 -c file.txt
```

In your case, `file.txt` would be your `md5checksums.txt` file.

Comment: How would I check the resulting value to the one given in a file along the md5s of other files? I should have made it clear that I would like to check the md5 values for all the files in the folder.

Comment: @JulioDiaz I don't thing I understand that question.  In my example, `file.txt` is the file that contains the MD5 checksums and pathnames.  `md5sum -c file.txt` will calculate the MD5 checksums of the files listed and compare them to the corresponding pre-calculated checksums.  You probably just need to use `md5checksums.txt` instead of `file.txt`.

Comment: I see. Is there a homologue to -c in md5?

Comment: @JulioDiaz You haven't yet said what type of Unix you are working with.

Comment: Im working from OSX

Comment: @JulioDiaz Then it would be _easiest_ to install GNU `coreutils`, e.g. from [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), and use its `md5sum` (which would be installed as `gmd5sum`).

Comment: This worked out I installed md5sum using `brew install md5sha1sum`